# How to connect Flutter backend with Django server?

Tags: django, flutter, dart, http, get

So, I have a **Django** server running on my computer on local host, port 8000 (http://127.0.0.1:8000) and I'm creating a **Flutter** application. I want to connect my **Flutter** app backend with the **Django** server but I don't know how. Here is what I tried:

First, I tried connecting to the computer's private ip address and it's not working:

```dart
Future<void> test() async {
    print('1');
    final url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.42:8000/users/');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response);
    print('2');
  }
```

Second, I tried connecting to local host:

```dart
Future<void> test() async {
    print('1');
    final url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/users/');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response);
    print('2');
  }
```

and I got this error:

> E/flutter (27014): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused

Finally I tried the local host adress equivalent, and I got the same error above:

```dart
Future<void> test() async {
    print('1');
    final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response);
    print('2');
  }
```

Comment: i also faced same problem when i started, i want to know if you are running flutter in your pc or mobile? if you are running flutter in your pc and your django server is also in pc then url would be final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/');  but if you are running in mobile then url would be final url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.42:8000/users/'); but make sure your mobile and your laptop are connected to same wifi (network).

Comment: @DhruvPatel I'm running flutter on my mobile, but when I type Uri.parse('192.168.1.42:8000/users/'); I'm getting this error: Unhandled Exception: No route to host

Comment: Make sure your mobile and laptop are connected to same wifi or a mobile hotspot

Comment: @DhruvPatel Yep they are, the problem that I faced this morning is that I noticed that I can't ping my computer from my phone, and I can't ping my phone or any other device connected to the netword from my computer, I don't know if it's related

Comment: in django settings.py do this ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*'
 ]  it will allow all applications to run, this may help you

Answer (score 0):

NOTE - Specific for connecting Android and django rest api in Flutter

I tried lot of things but connection timeout was occuring. I was using django Rest-Api

go to Command Prompt type ipconfig copy ipv4 address in my case 192.168.0.201
[image]

add 192.168.0.201 in ALLOWED_HOST =[] in django settings.py.
[image]

type "python manage.py runserver 192.168.2.4:8000" to run your server.
[image]

4)In Flutter your baseurl for accesing django rest api should be "http://192.168.0.201:8000/"

This worked for me.

Thanks!